# Azure Policy exemption not working as expected

Tags: azure-policy

Playing around with Azure Policy. Assigned the policy Storage account public access should be disallowed to a resource group. In it, I already had one storage account with public access enabled. If I check the compliance status, I can indeed see one resource marked as non-compliant.

[image: compliance state]

Next, I’ve created an exemption since I still want the resource to by evaluated for compliance (unlike with exclusions, as the resource wouldn’t be evaluated or included in the compliance count), however this seams not to work as expected.

[image: exempted]

The resource still shows up in the compliance view as non-compliant:

[image: wrrong state]

Quoting from the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/scope

> Resources in this state show as Exempted in compliance reports so that
> they can be tracked.

Any idea as to what is going on ?

Comment: Please share the Policy in JSON format.

Comment: @SoySolisCarlos Thank you for you answer. The status changed to Exempt after some time. Are you aware if there’s any delay for this to kick in? Also, could you please confirm that an Exempted resource basically will be excluded from policy (effect) evaluation, even if it is in a non-compliant state, correct? Meaning the deny effect will not affect the exempted resource ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog article about manually triggering compliance evaluations](https://www.danielstechblog.io/trigger-an-on-demand-azure-policy-compliance-evaluation-scan/) it takes either up to 24 hours (for existing items) or 30 minutes (for new items) to be scanned for compliance. It appears that you ran into that issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it was really helpful.  You deserve an upvote as I did!